# Why am I getting a garbage value at the end of C malloc?

Tags: c, encryption, undefined-behavior, garbage

I'm writing encryption and decryption functions that work as follows:

```
encrypt("string") -> "encryptedString"
decrypt("encryptedString") -> "string"
```

However, I'm getting weird results when I run them.

In my example, I'm encrypting `ab#z,A1BZ` in order to get: `bc#a,Z1AY` and vise versa (decryption)

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
Question 3a (encrypt): bc#a,Z1AY
Question 3b (decrypt): ab#z,A1BZcuments�v�j�
```

I would like to stress that the function seems to be doing it's job correctly. Notice that `ab#z,A1BZ` is part of the decrypt output. THAT part is correct. However it's followed by `cuments�v�j�`

`decrypt("bc#a,Z1AY")` should only result in `ab#z,A1BZ`

**Here are the functions:**

```
char* encrypt(const char* plaintext){
    char* ciphertext = malloc((strlen(plaintext) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++){
        if (islower(plaintext[i])){
            char c;
            if (plaintext[i] == 'z'){
                c = 'a';
            }
            else {
                c = plaintext[i] + 1;
            }
            ciphertext[i] = c;
        }
        else if (isupper(plaintext[i])){
            char c;
            if (plaintext[i] == 'A'){
            c = 'Z';
            }
            else {
            c = plaintext[i] - 1;
            }
            ciphertext[i] = c;
        }
        else {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
        }
    }
    return ciphertext;
}

char* decrypt(const char* ciphertext){
    char* plaintext = malloc((strlen(ciphertext) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ciphertext); i++){
        if (islower(ciphertext[i])){
            char c;
            if (ciphertext[i] == 'a'){
                c = 'z';
            }
            else {
                c = ciphertext[i] - 1;
            }
            plaintext[i] = c;
        }
        else if (isupper(ciphertext[i])){
            char c;
            if (ciphertext[i] == 'Z'){
                 c = 'A';
            }
            else {
                c = ciphertext[i] + 1;
            }
            plaintext[i] = c;
        }
        else {
            plaintext[i] = ciphertext[i];
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

**And this is the calling/driver code:**

```
char* ciphertext = encrypt("ab#z,A1BZ");
char* plaintext = decrypt(ciphertext);
printf("Question 3a (encrypt): %s\n", ciphertext);
printf("Question 3b (decrypt): %s\n", plaintext);
free(ciphertext);
free(plaintext);
```

Where `SIZE` is defined as 8

Comment: Where have you NUL-terminated the string you created? You included the byte in `malloc`, but forgot to write it (or assumed it would be `0`).

Comment: can you the code that can compile?

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C are [null-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). The functions, such as `printf()` or `strlen()`, expect a null byte at the end of the string, which is a byte with the value zero.

When you [dynamically allocate memory in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc), you have it assigned by the operating system. When calling `malloc()` (as opposed to `calloc()`), you have no guarantee what the contents of the memory will be when you receive it. That is the reason your code has undefined behavior - when the memory returned by the system happens to have `0` as the last byte, your code will run fine. If there's anything else, the `printf()` will continue writing the output.

You should account for this behavior and explicitly set the last byte of the string to `0`:

```c
int ciphertext_len = strlen(ciphertext);

// allocate ciphertext_len + 1 bytes for the plaintext output

for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext_len; i++) {
    // your substitution logic
    // plaintext[i] = ...
}

plaintext[ciphertext_len] = 0;
```

Other alternative, which is considered to be a safe practice, is always zeroing out the memory you receive using `memset()`:

```c
#include <string.h>

// store the size in bytes of the memory block you wish to allocate
int mem_block_size = (strlen(ciphertext) + 1) * sizeof(char);

// allocate the memory
char * plaintext = malloc(mem_block_size);

// set the memory to zeroes
memset(plaintext, 0, mem_block_size);
```

Comment: So sorry but using `memset()` does not work. The pointer returned from `decrypt()` still points to a block with garbage values at the end.

Comment: I have admittedly made a mistake. The `memset()`, as I previously wrote it, was a general way to zero out an array of chars (`char plaintext[]`). It didn't apply in your scenario, since what you have is a pointer to a char (`char * plaintext`). The call `sizeof(plaintext)` returned the size of a pointer - which can be 4 or 8 bytes. In your case, you need to store the size individually to use for zeroing the memory later. I have updated my answer.